# Распознавание текста из картинки java

Tags: java, распознавание-символов

Мне надо распознавать текст из картинки накладной товара, которую будет фотографировать сканер принтера и размещать на компьютере, я не знаю проблема ли это но накладные размещены в таблицах.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какая то библиотека по этому поводу, может посоветуете почитать что нибудь по этой теме ? Я пробовал одну библиотеку, но что то она вообще путается. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вам надо что-то от [ABBYY](https://www.abbyy.com/ru-ru/scan-station/). У них есть готовые решения по сканированию бланков. Для Java подобных библиотек никогда не видел.

Comment: Спасибо, из java можно это использовать как native библиотеку ?

Comment: см. [Java Wrapper for FineReader Engine](https://abbyy.technology/en:kb:code-sample:java-wrapper)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду разбираться.